# Verifying affine spaces in Xoodoo component

Tags: symmetric

I am reading ["The design of Xoodoo and Xoofff"](https://tosc.iacr.org/index.php/ToSC/article/view/7359/6529). On page 13 there is a collorary related to the component $\chi$ [Algorithm 1, 1].

> **Corollary 1.** For fixed (difference or mask) $a$, the compatible (difference or mask) $b$ values form an affine space of dimension 2 and vice-versa

I am trying to verify this corollary exhaustively. That is I have fixed a $b$ and generated all $a$. Specifically, I took $b=110$. For this value, the corresponding possible $a$'s are $S=\{010, 100, 011, 101\}$. My question is Does $S$ form an affine space of dimension 2? if so, why?